# Why does Robocopy ignore the /copy flags?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, robocopy

### Robocopy Copy Flags?

I just recently made an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211788/891976 where I suggested using `robocopy` and its `/copy` flags, but for some as of yet unknown reason, the `/copy` flags are being ignored.

This was originally noted by dbenham, but I too have confirmed that when I specified the `/copy:DA` flag, `robocopy` just ignored it and did a full `DAT` copy.

[Robocopy Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

### Script

```
@echo off
robocopy Tools Tolls /COPY:DA /S /IS
pause >nul
```

### Output

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon Mar 04 16:59:43 2013

   Source : C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Tools\
     Dest : C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Tolls\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /COPY:DAT /IS /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          New Dir          5    C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Tools\
100%        New File                 825        Connect.bat
100%        New File                 424        DevSpec.bat
100%        New File                 215        Disconnect.bat
100%        New File               69599        Shortcuts.zip
100%        New File              28.8 m        Tools.zip

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Files :         5         5         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   28.87 m   28.87 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :           150632582 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            8619.265 MegaBytes/min.

   Ended : Mon Mar 04 16:59:43 2013
```

#### Anyone have insight into why the `/copy` flag did not work?

Comment: What timestamp should robocopy use if you don't specify the T flag?

Comment: @AbqBill - The assumption would be the current system timestamp.

Comment: @AbqBill  I am just making an assumption since the functionality appears to be undocumented, but if you do not copy the time stamps, then it would seem to make sense to use the current time.  However, I am unable to even verify this since it is ignoring my `/copy` flags.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my guess is that it assumes T if you specify A or D. Experiment and see.

Comment: @AbqBill Indeed I am trying many different combinations.  So far `/COPY:DT` works, `/COPY:A` works, but when I just specify `/COPY:D` is automatically appends the `T`.  So far it appears to make the `T` required when `D` is used.  I am trying to figure it out, but any insight to the **undocumented behavior** is appreciated.

Comment: This may be an implementation side-effect. I'm not sure the author(s) anticipated your use case. If you really need to use the current time after copying, this is pretty easily accomplished using PowerShell.

Comment: @AbqBill  Side-Effect or not it is undocumented behavior since the documentation gives all indication that this is a valid use case.  Therefore, it could also be classified as a bug in design.  For it supports a `DA` option for the `DCOPY` but not the `COPY`. That is a very inconsistent implementation, that has a need to be documented.

Comment: This behavior is as designed and documented. See my answer below for documentation.

Comment: @KevinFegan **This behavior is not documented in an current official documentation.**  XP010 is 17 version / 10 years old.  So should I scour all of Java 1.4 documentation and say that is more correct over the Java 1.7 documentation when I am using version 1.7?

Comment: @DavidRuhmann, Any way that we can get our hands on the source code or actual workings?

Comment: @Pacerier,  There is no available of the robocopy source code that I know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Undocumented Behavior

Well it would appear the undocumented behavior is as follows:

Whenever, the `D` flag is used for `/COPY`, `robocopy` will automatically add the `T` flag.

However, this does not apply to the directory `/DCOPY` flag.  It can be specified without `T` and work.

#### Tested (no files are copied without D, only folders)

```
/Copy:D becomes /Copy:DT
/Copy:A becomes /DCopy:DA /Copy:A
/Copy:T becomes /DCopy:D /Copy:T
/Copy:DT becomes /DCopy:D /Copy:DT
/Copy:AT becomes /DCopy:DA /Copy:AT
```

**Note:** tested on *Windows 7 64 bit* and *Windows 8 64 bit*.

Comment: How would you specify **`/DCOPY`** without including **`T`**, and what would it mean? The only (documented) valid option to **`/DCOPY`** is **`T`** (so only **`/DCOPY:T`**). See the Command line reference here:  [Updated: April 17, 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx). Particularly the **`D`** option seems meaningless with **`/DCOPY`**... how would (should) the behavior of **`/DCOPY:DT`** be different than **`/DCOPY:T`**?

Comment: ***...Well it would appear the undocumented behavior is as follows...*** this is ***documented*** behavior. See the documentation here: [XP010](http://theether.net/download/Microsoft/Utilities/robocopy.pdf)

Comment: I'm curious, Is this document still provided by an official Microsoft source?  Also this document is about 17 version / 10 years old.  **Yet, the behavior is still undocumented in all the current official documentation.**

Comment: ***'... Is this document still provided by an official Microsoft source?'*** Yes, while 10 years old, it is the most current **full official Microsoft documentation** available for Robocopy. It is currently available as **`Robocopy.doc`** for **XP010** version when you download the current version of [**Robocopy GUI**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/UtilitySpotlight2006_11.exe). (Note: **Robocopy GUI** includes version **XP026** of **`Robocopy.exe`** and version **XP010** of **`Robocopy.doc`**).

Comment: @KevinFegan, And so how do we check which version our Robocopy is using?

Comment: @Pacerier - 1) Using Windows Explorer (explorer.exe), navigate to your copy of Robocopy.exe. Mine is located in "C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe". 2)  Right-click on "Robocopy.exe" and select "Properties". 3) Go to the "Details" Tab and look for "File version:", and "Product version:". For mine (Windows 7 x64), I have: "File version: 5.1.10.1027", and "Product version: XP027".

Comment: @KevinFegan  Something to note, it would seem that Microsoft has dropped the XP0## version notation.  On Windows 8.1, I only see 6.3.9600.17415 as both the File and Product version.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, and also it is not undocumented.

According to the Robocopy Documentation:

> **`Note:`** `If file Data is copied, then file Timestamps are also copied.`

This is from page 6 in this document: [XP010](http://theether.net/download/Microsoft/Utilities/robocopy.pdf)

---

About the **XP010** document linked above:

While 10 years old, as of the date of this posting, it is the most current **full official Microsoft** documentation available for **Robocopy**. It is currently available as **`Robocopy.doc`** for **XP010** version when you download the current version of [Robocopy GUI](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/UtilitySpotlight2006_11.exe) from Microsoft website. (Note: **Robocopy GUI** includes version **XP026** of **`Robocopy.exe`** and version **XP010** of **`Robocopy.doc`**).

As of the date of this posting, no (printed or electronic/downloadable) **full official Microsoft** documentation is available for Robocopy version XP026 or XP027.

Comment: Interesting, So the only mention of it is in a document from 2003 for version XP010.  **But it is undocumented in all current official documentation.**  Windows 7 Version = XP027.

Comment: ***'...this document is about 17 version old...'*** actually 2 versions old. After XP010 was version XP026 then XP027. The document I linked, while 10 years old, is the most current **full official Microsoft documentation** available for Robocopy.

Comment: Again, Interesting. The only place where this document was released was through a [TechNet blog (November 2006)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx) with the release of a  tool "RoboCopy GUI" ([Abandonware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware)).  And incorrect, that document is **not** the **most current full official Microsoft documentation**. This is: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx or this `robocopy /?`.  Also note that this tool is not by the official robocopy owners but a MSN Search group worker.

Comment: @david-ruhmann Interesting - I was not aware of the Robocopy documentation on TechNet. However, it is _much less_ detailed than the XP010 version of the document. The explanation of the commands in XP010 missing from the TechNet document is **extremely helpful**! Still, I have read that document dozens of times, but _never_ noticed that note on page 6, nor the sentence on page 20: `However, if file data is copied, file timestamps are also copied.`